# How to add faces while using a Mirror modifier?

Tags: faces, mirror-modifier

[image]

While I was making this chair leg I wanted to add faces on the front side of the leg (picture), but I couldn't or they were quite glitchy.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, your Mirror modifier doesn't have "Clipping" checked.  For what you're doing you should, this prevents geometry from crossing the 0 point (on the X axis, according to your settings) which can cause what your describing.

I recommend you turn off your mirror modifier (or delete it), make sure none of your geometry is on the made-by-mirror side of 0 on the X axis (not so much as a single vertex), then start using the Mirror modifier again with Clipping checked.  (Remember the position of Mirror in your modifier stack, you'll usually want it at or near the top.)